# Graph API Java SDK Send Mail with attached EML that has attachments at the same time not delivering

Tags: java, graph, microsoft-graph-api

The code does not returns any error or exception, it runs successfully but the email is never delivered.
I have the following code where I am sending an EML as an attachment using the sendMail method of the Graph API Java sdk.
This EML file has at the same time embedded attachments. On any other case it is sending correctly the mail using the Graph API but in this particular case it is not working. Here is the code I am using.

```
    Message message = new Message();
message.subject = "Analysis Result Malicious Emails";
ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
body.contentType = BodyType.HTML;
body.content = contentHtmlTemplate;
message.body = body;

LinkedList < Attachment > attachmentsList = new LinkedList < Attachment > ();
FileAttachment attachments = new FileAttachment();
attachments.name = randomIdentifier;
attachments.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
attachments.oDataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment";
try {
    attachments.contentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File("Attachments/" + randomIdentifier).toPath());
    attachmentsList.add(attachments);
    AttachmentCollectionResponse attachmentCollectionResponse = new AttachmentCollectionResponse();
    attachmentCollectionResponse.value = attachmentsList;
    message.attachments = new AttachmentCollectionPage(attachmentCollectionResponse, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

message.toRecipients = resolveEmailTeamRecipients();

boolean saveToSentItems = false;

GraphUtils.userClient.me()
    .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
        .newBuilder()
        .withMessage(message)
        .withSaveToSentItems(saveToSentItems)
        .build())
    .buildRequest()
    .post();
```

[This is the CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpfY0.png)

I have tried changing the content Type and the odataType and it is still not delivering. Any other EML files that do not have embedded attachments are working correctly

Comment: given the subject of the Message "Analysis Result Malicious Emails" is it that the content is Malicous so the email is being quarantined ? you should be able to do a Message Trace on one of you send attempts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/message-trace-scc?view=o365-worldwide this will tell you if the service is taking any actions